# replacing specific value (from another file) using awk

Tags: shell, awk

I have a following file.

**File1**

```
a b 1
c d 2
e f 3
```

**File2**

```
x l
y m
z n
```

I want to replace `1` by `x` at a time and save in a `file3`. next time `1` to `y` and save in `file4`.

Then files look like

**File3**

```
a b x
c d 2
e f 3
```

**File4**

```
a b y
c d 2
e f 3
```

once I finished `x`, `y`, `z` then `2` by `l`, `m` and `n`.

I start with this but it inserts but does not replace.

```
awk -v r=1 -v c=3 -v val=x -F, '
    BEGIN{OFS=" "}; NR != r; NR == r {$c = val; print}
' file1 >file3
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a gnu awk script ( because it uses multidimensional arrays, array ordering ) that will do what you want:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN { fcnt=3 }

FNR==NR { for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) f2[i][NR]=$i; next }

{
    fout[FNR][1] = $0
    ff = $NF
    if(ff in f2) {
        for( r in f2[ff]) {
            $NF = f2[ff][r]
            fout[FNR][fcnt++] = $0
        }
    }
}

END {
    for(f=fcnt-1;f>=3;f--) {
        for( row in fout ) {
            if( fout[row][f] != "" ) out = fout[row][f]
            else out = fout[row][1]
            print out > "file" f
        }
    }
}
```

I made at least one major assumption about your input data:

- The field number in `file2` corresponds exactly to the value that needs to be replaced in `file1`.  For example, `x` is field 1 in `file2`, and `1` is what needs replacing in the output files.

Here's the breakdown:

- Set `fcnt=3` in the `BEGIN` block.
- `FNR==NR` - store the contents of `File2` in the `f2` array by (field number, line number).
- Store the original `f1` line in `fout` as (line number,1) - where `1` is a special, available array position ( because `fcnt` starts at 3 ).
- Save off `$NF` as `ff` because it's going to be reset
- Whenever `ff` is a field number in the first subscript of the `f2` array, then reset `$NF` to the value from `file2` and then assign the result to `fout` at (line number, file number) as `$0` ( recomputed ).
- In the `END`, loop over the `fcnt` in reverse order, and either set `out` to a replaced line value or an original line value in `row` order, then print `out` to the desired filename.

It could be run like `gawk -f script.awk file2 file1` ( notice the file order ).  I get the following output:

```
$ cat file[3-8]
a b x
c d 2
e f 3
a b y
c d 2
e f 3
a b z
c d 2
e f 3
a b 1
c d l
e f 3
a b 1
c d m
e f 3
a b 1
c d n
e f 3
```

This could be made more efficient for memory by only performing the lookup in the `END` block, but I wanted to take advantage of the `$0` recompute instead of needing calls to `split` in the `END`.